# Verbb Feed Me for Craft 3 - Possible to read assets from local disk?

Tags: plugin-feedme

In https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me/docs/content-mapping/field-types#assets the documentation says yes, but I cannot get it to work.

I also find the documentation confusing: "You should supply the filename only, excluding the full path to the asset". How can it even know where to get the file then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files and assets are two different concepts. An asset represents a file already in Craft, and you'll be able to search and browse for it in the Assets section. Whereas in a number of different cases, you'll want to create (upload) an asset from a URL.

If you have an existing asset in Craft already, so you don't want to upload it, then provide just the filename and extension in your feed. This is as per the documentation.

If you want to create an asset from a remote URL, you'll need to tick the "Create asset from URL" checkbox in the mapping screen for Feed Me. If you do this option however, you'll need to provide an **absolute URL** to the file you want to import into Craft.

So, with the above in mind, the short answer to your question is that Feed Me doesn't support creating assets from a local path, but it does support it from a local URL. You'll need to change the path in your feed to point to a full URL, which you can achieve by moving it to a folder in your project, or setting up a virtual host in your favourite local dev environment.